# Help proving $\left|e^{-(s-1/2)\log(s)}e^s\right|\ll_\varepsilon e^{|s|^{1+\varepsilon}}$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I'm trying to [work through this proof](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/number_theory/riemann_hadamard_product.pdf) and I'm stuck at the fourth equation down on page 2. Firstly, there is a typo in that the coefficient $\sqrt{2\pi}$ should be $1/(\sqrt{2\pi})$. I believe there is a second typo which is that it should read $\ll_\varepsilon e^{|s|^{1+\varepsilon}}$ not $\ll_\varepsilon e^{|s|^\varepsilon}$ (empirical results using limits support this). The first typo is inconsequential, but assuming the second corrected typo I'm now trying to prove
$$\left|e^{-(s-1/2)\log(s)}e^s\right|\ll_\varepsilon e^{|s|^{1+\varepsilon}},\tag{*}$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$, where $\text{Re}(s)\geq\delta>0$, presumably for some $\delta>0$.

I manipulated the left hand side,
$$|e^{-(s-1/2)\log s+s}|=|e^{-(\sigma-1/2)\log|s|+t\text{Arg}(s)+\sigma}|.$$
So we need to show for some $C>0$ that
$$e^{-(\sigma-1/2)\log|s|+t\text{Arg}(s)+\sigma}<Ce^{|s|^{1+\varepsilon}}.$$
I'm stuck at this point and can't seem to prove the inequality. Any help or a hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $C = e^c$ to get things down from the exponents. You want to show that for a sufficiently large $c$ (depending on $\varepsilon$) the inequality
$$-(\sigma - 1/2)\log \lvert s\rvert + t\operatorname{Arg}(s) + \sigma \leqslant \lvert s\rvert^{1 + \varepsilon} + c$$
holds throughout the half-plane $\sigma \geqslant \delta$.

For this we can be pretty brutal. Write $x = \lvert s\rvert$ and note that $\sigma \leqslant x$, $\lvert t\rvert \leqslant x$, and the argument is bounded (in absolute value) by $\pi/2$. Thus it suffices to see that
$$(x + 1/2) \lvert\log x\rvert + \pi/2 x + x \leqslant x^{1+\varepsilon} + c$$
holds on the interval $[\delta, +\infty)$ if $c$ is sufficiently large. But
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\log x}{x^{\varepsilon}} = 0$$
implies
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \:\bigl((x+1/2)\lvert \log x\rvert + (1 + \pi/2)x - x^{1+\varepsilon}\bigr) = -\infty\,,$$
so the function on the left is bounded from above, as we wanted to show.

To see that it's indeed a typo and $e^{\lvert s\rvert^{\varepsilon}}$ on the right hand side does not work, consider $s = \frac{1}{2} + it$. For large $\lvert t\rvert$ we have
$$\Bigl\lvert e^{-(s-1/2)\log s + s}\Bigr\rvert \geqslant e^{\lvert t\rvert}$$
but
$$e^{\lvert s\rvert^{\varepsilon}} < e^{(2\lvert t\rvert)^{\varepsilon}}\,,$$
which shows the inequality
$$\Bigl\lvert e^{-(s-1/2)\log s + s}\Bigr\rvert \leqslant Ce^{\lvert s\rvert^{\varepsilon}}$$
cannot hold for $\varepsilon < 1$.

Comment: Given any $\eta > 0$, for large enough $x$ we have $\frac{\log x}{x^{\varepsilon}} < \eta$. Thus (assume $x \geqslant e$, so $\log x \geqslant 1$) $$(x + 1/2)\log x + (1 + \pi/2)x - x^{1 + \varepsilon} < 2x\log x + (1+\pi/2)x - x^{1+\varepsilon} = x^{1+\varepsilon}\biggl(\frac{2\log x}{x^{\varepsilon}} + \frac{1+\pi/2}{x} - 1\biggr) < x^{1+\varepsilon}(5\eta - 1)\,.$$ Taking $\eta < 1/5$ makes the right hand side tend to $-\infty$.

Comment: Just to clarify the second limit? We have:
$$(x+1/2)|\log x|+(1+\pi/2)x-x^{1+\varepsilon}=x|\log x|-x^{1+\varepsilon}+O(x)\to-\infty$$ as $x\to\infty$ (which I can see results from the first limit).

Comment: Yes, that works too.